# How to type on an input box via JavaScript for IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Trying to figure out how to type (via events not set the value) on an input box for IE8 and 9. I looked at some of the examples on the web - but couldn't get any of they to work. (I don't want to rely on jQuery of other libraries).

Here is what I have so far:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txtfld" /> 
  <input type="button" onclick="typeKey()" /> 
</form>
<script>

function typeKey(){
    var  txtField = document.getElementById('txtfld');
    var evt= document.createEventObject();
    evt.keyCode=68;
    txtField.fireEvent('onkeypress', evt);
}
</script>
```

It does not work, and it does not give an error either.

Comment: Why do you need to call the event in this way? Could you not just say document.getElementById('txtField').value = U; runEvent()

Comment: You need to fire `keypress`, not `onkeypress`.

Comment: @theedam it is just a requirement i have. It should be possible, and I want to learn how to get it working.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine "keypress" does not work on IE. You need onkeypress
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536390(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function, `fire(document.getElementById('txtfld'),'keypress',68)`:

```
function fire(el,evttype,code) {
   if (document.createEvent) {
     var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
     evt.initEvent( evttype, false, false);
     evt.charCode= evt.keyCode = code;
     el.dispatchEvent(evt);
   } else if (document.createEventObject) {
     var evt = document.createEventObject();
     evt.charCode= evt.keyCode = code;
     el.fireEvent('on' + evttype, evt);
   }
}
```

[here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HfU6Q/4/)

good luck :)

Comment: The code is missing the definition of evt for the "document.createEventObject" case. Even when defining it as:
var evt = document.createEventObject;
it still does not work

Comment: You were right, I forgot to call createEventObject *and pass the evt*. See now the code, I'd tried the example on IE and it's working fine.

Comment: Are you trying the last example? http://jsfiddle.net/HfU6Q/4/ ? What do you see when you press go button? can i see your code and how are you implementing this function?

Comment: Actually i tis working.. i was just expecting the textbox would also pick the value, but it is not.