# Is it possible to generate a virtual keyboardEvent (tab) in IE8 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events, keyboard-events

I want to generate a virtual keyboardEvent(tab). I did some research on the same and got few usefully answers, however it not working for me. I understand that Javascript is event driven programming language so User should press require key, but I also want to understand that can we generate an keyboard event through JavaScript.

```
function fnGenerateTabKeyEvent() {
    var e = document.createEventObject("KeyboardEvent");
    e.keyCode = 9; // tab's ASCII
    document.getElementsByName("someTxtBox").fireEvent("onkeyup", e);
}
<input type="text" id="someTxtBox"/>
```

It's not working in IE8 and I'm not getting any error either. I just want that whenever I can this function it should an keyboardevent(tab) from that text box.

[Source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518664/how-can-i-generate-a-keyup-event-with-a-specific-keycode-in-ie8),[Source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083872/how-to-type-on-an-input-box-via-javascript-for-ie). Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @razvan I'm using JavaScript. Is this possible in JQuery?

Comment: You can trigger events with jQuery. [example](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/simulating-keypress-events)

Comment: yeah, would be easier with jquery and with better browser coverage

Comment: can you share some piece of code if you have handy?

Comment: @i-- This code will be running on IE8 only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were too hasty, as your code works on my machine:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="someTxtBox" onkeyup="window.alert(event.keyCode)"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fnGenerateTabKeyEvent() {
    var e = document.createEventObject("KeyboardEvent");
    e.keyCode = 9; // tab's ASCII
    document.getElementById("someTxtBox").fireEvent("onkeyup", e);
}

fnGenerateTabKeyEvent();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There're of course some "issues" (like - accessing elements via `getElementsByName`, maybe having the script called before the `<input>`, but let's blame that on copy-pasting ;)) As such, on my IE, running in document mode 8 the alert successfully displays 9.

Comment: From IE9 forward and for all other browsers you use createEvent() and dispatchEvent() rather than createEventObject and fireEvent(). The leading 'on' in the event name is also dropped. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/921640

Comment: @ClearCrescendo None of these methods appears to work at all with keyboard events!